# Memory warning IOS 6 App Dev with low live bytes in instrument

Tags: iphone, memory, warnings, cgimage, ios6

I am updating app to make it compatible with IOS 6, getting memory warning. live bytes in instrument shows low usage (2.3 MB). In VM tracker dirty size gets around 50%. in VM Tracker type = CG Image -> dirty size increases to 100%. My app requires users to take pictures but i am not using any core graphics objects. is there a way to release CG Image dirty memory ? thank you for taking time and reviewing my request.

Comment: Have you checked your application using heap shots to see where your memory accumulation is occurring? Live Bytes is useless as a measure of your application's total memory consumption. Instead, use Memory Monitor to observe that.

Comment: Hi Brad, Heap shots and Memory activity monitor seems ok, Looks like app is throwing memory warning due to Virtual memory usage growing over 190MB

Answer (score 0):

My app using ARC starting leaking memory very badly on iOS6 whilst it ran perfectly on iOS5. When I say "leaking", I actually mean allocating memory and then not releasing the memory properly when I removed objects from mutable arrays, causing the app's memory usage to increase dramatically.

After lots of frustration, I've managed to fix it by setting up an @autoreleasepool { ... } around the offending section.

My suspicion is that iOS6 is threading my app differently compared with iOS5, as there used to be an @autorelease pool covering that process.

I suggest you try that solution as it is very quick to implement.